# What does it mean when people refer to Firebase as a back-end-as-a-service?

Tags: firebase

I'm mainly wondering because when I ask what language Firebase uses, devs have said that that's not exactly how it works, and that Firebase is instead a "back-end-as-a-service."

What does this mean? Does it mean that Firebase can handle everything that a back-end language would handle? And how does Firebase handle more complex operations, for example text input parsing (NLP) that languages like Python can accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backend as a Service is usually abbreviated BaaS.  The [formal definition from Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_backend_as_a_service) it is:

> a model for providing web app and mobile app developers with a way to
>   link their applications to backend cloud storage and APIs exposed by
>   back end applications while also providing features such as user
>   management, push notifications, and integration with social networking
>   services. These services are provided via the use of custom
>   software development kits (SDKs) and application programming
>   interfaces (APIs).

Basically, if you're building an app, you don't have to set up any backend infrastructure to get started.  You just use the provided SDKs to access the provided backend products directly.

> Does it mean that Firebase can handle everything that a back-end language would handle?

This question doesn't really make sense, since there is really no such thing as a "backend language".  There are backend services, but programming languages are not classified as "frontend" or "backend".

> And how does Firebase handle more complex operations, for example text input parsing (NLP) that languages like Python can accomplish?

Firebase doesn't directly handle these things.  Firebase is part of the Google Cloud platform, which does have [NLP products](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/) that you can read about, but you can't invoke them directly from a mobile app in the way the BaaS implies.  You would have to write and deploy code to another backend service to invoke them.